# deletion of file after 7 days

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to delete multiple files after 7 days regularly. And the deletion dates and location are different for each file.Yes, I can apply a cronjob for each folder separately but tat will involve many cronjobs (atleast 15).
In order to avoid this, I want to create a script which will go to each folder and delete the data.
For example:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 csbackup other    20223605295 Jun 12 06:40 IO.tgz
```

As you can see IO.tgz was created on 12/06/2015 6:40... now I want to delete this file at 17/06/2015 00:00 hours... this is one reason I'm unable to use mtime as it will delete exactly after 7*24 hrs.

I was thinking to compare the timestamps of the file however, stat utility is not present on my machine. And its now even allowing me to install it.

Can anyone please guide me via a script which I can use to delete after n days

Comment: How much resources do you think a cron job that is not running consumes? It takes the same amount of diskspace that the crontab line itself uses (often under 80 characters). How much compute time does it take while not running? Literally none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of directories you want to search in a file.

```
# cat file
/data
/d01
/u01/files/
```

Now you can use `for` loop to remove the files which are there on those directories one by one.

```
for dir in $(cat file); do 
    find $dir -type f -mtime 7 |xargs rm -f
done
```

Comment: Maybe will better: `find $(cat file) -type f -mtime 7 -delete` - you don't need `for`-loop and `xargs` and `rm` - `find` will do everything :)

Comment: but using mtime 7 .. wont it delete exact after 7*24hrs when the file was modified. As the file in example was modified at 6am.. however, i want to delete it at 00:00 hrs after 7 days (in terms of date)